# Drawing intersection over union in equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, intersections

I'm new to LaTeX and I try to use `tikz` library to draw intersection over union in an equation like in the following image, but sadly I couldn't find any solution for it.

[image: iou]

The current state of my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,3) node[anchor=north west] {$IoU = \frac{\text{area of overlap}}{\text{area of union}}=$}
$\frac{
\draw[blue, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[blue, very thick] (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);
}{
\filldraw[color=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\filldraw[color=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick] (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);
}$
\end{tikzpicture}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

but the result looks like this:
[image: iou_selfmade]

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. In the future, when you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll notice that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two separate tikz pictures for the numerator and denominator. Note that in the code below, I used the shorthand `tikz{...}` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` to make the code easier to read (in my opinion).

[image]

For the denominator, use a single `\fill` command for both rectangles. For the numerator, we want an odd-even fill, so first fill the whole figure with light blue and then use `even odd rule` to fill the outer portions with white.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

$IoU = \frac{\text{area of overlap}}{\text{area of union}}=
\frac{
    \tikz{\fill[draw=blue, very thick, fill=blue!5] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);
    \fill[draw=blue, very thick, fill=white, even odd rule] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);}}
{\tikz{\fill[draw=blue, fill=blue!5, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);}}$

\end{document}
```